# How to strip mutiple strings in python

Tags: python, list, strip

I have list (in text file)

```
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=3,VAL=-90
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=4,VAL=-91
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=5,VAL=-92
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=5,VAL=-92
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=6,VAL=-91
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-77
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-82
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=8,VAL=-88
```

and I want my output to be like this,

```
[['B2', '3', '-90'], 
 ['B2', '4', '-91'],
 ['B2', '5', '-92'],
 ['B2', '5', '-92'],
 ['B2', '6', '-91'],
 ['B2', '7', '-77'],
 ['B2', '7', '-82'], 
 ['B2', '8', '-88']]
```

I tried this code, but I am not able to strip what I wanted.

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    k = []
    for i in d:
        m=i.strip('<info> app:').strip('Bid=').strip('Bts=').strip('VAL=').strip('\n').split(',')
        k.append(m)
    print (k)
```

How to strip what I want??What am I missing??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just wait for one of the many `regex` ninjas to come up with a wonderful solution!

Comment: Can you use [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)?

Comment: Have a look at https://regex101.com/r/mUZBqU/1 .

Comment: Want it as pythonic as possible with fewer codes.configparser I tried but just couldn't grasp my head around it.

Comment: @KlausD. new to regex so a step by step explanation about whats happening in the link would help!

Comment: There is everything on the page including a code generator.

Comment: Can you tell us whether the `'<info>'` part is literally that, or might it contain other characters in reality?

Comment: @quamrana its literally just that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split by `,` and then `=`, and finally takes what's after `=`.

```
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    k = []
    for i in d:
        k.append([j.split("=")[1] for j in i.split(",")])
    print (k)
```

Comment: hey small question how to strip '\n' at the end??

Comment: Can you try `k.append([j.split("=")[1].strip() for j in i.split(",")])` @ShubhamKuse

Comment: @ShubhamKuse is that you have blank lines in the end? If that is the case, use `d = f.readlines().strip()`.

Comment: @ShubhamKuse got you!

Answer (score 2):

[`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip%20str.strip) does not create structure; it merely removes the characters you indicate (by default, whitespace) from either end of a string. You're looking for something to parse your formatted fields, a notably more complex task. One possible example (using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)) might be:

```
>>> a
['<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-77',
 '<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-82',
 '<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=8,VAL=-88']
>>> import re
>>> fieldextractor=re.compile(' Bid=([^,]*),Bts=([^,]*),VAL=(.*)$')
>>> [fieldextractor.search(line).groups() for line in a]
[('B2', '7', '-77'), ('B2', '7', '-82'), ('B2', '8', '-88')]
```

Comment: your answer was almost as good as @tai but nevertheless thanks for regex exaplanation!

Answer (score 1):

With `re.search()` function:

```
import re

with open('list.txt') as f:
    result = []
    pat = re.compile(r'Bid=([^,]+),Bts=(\d+),VAL=([^\s]+)')
    for r in f:
        result.append(list(pat.search(r).groups()))

print(result)
```

The ouptut:

```
[['B2', '3', '-90'], ['B2', '4', '-91'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '6', '-91'], ['B2', '7', '-77'], ['B2', '7', '-82'], ['B2', '8', '-88']]
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.regex.search

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
lines = [
    '<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=3,VAL=-90',
    '<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=4,VAL=-91'
]
res = [[part.split('=')[1] for part in line.split(',')] for line in lines]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the for loop version you were trying to write:

```
src='''<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=3,VAL=-90
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=4,VAL=-91
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=5,VAL=-92
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=5,VAL=-92
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=6,VAL=-91
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-77
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=7,VAL=-82
<info> app: Bid=B2,Bts=8,VAL=-88'''

lines = src.split('\n')

k = []
for line in lines:
    bbv = line.split('app:')[1]  # split on 'app:' so that nothing in <info> interferes
    items = bbv.split(',')
    contents = [item.split('=')[1] for item in items]
    k.append(contents)

print(k)
```

Output:

```
[['B2', '3', '-90'], ['B2', '4', '-91'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '6', '-91'], ['B2', '7', '-77'], ['B2', '7', '-82'], ['B2', '8', '-88']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to print the desired output,

```
import re
with open('list.txt', 'r') as f:
    d = f.readlines()
    k = []
    for i in d:
        #m=i.strip('<info> app:').strip('Bid=').strip('Bts=').strip('VAL=').strip('\n').split(',')
        p = re.compile(r'Bid=(.*),Bts=(.*),VAL=(.*)')
        m = p.search(i)
        k.append([m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)])
    print (k)
```

And the output,

```
root@localhost [ ~ ]# python t.py
[['B2', '3', '-90'], ['B2', '4', '-91'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '5', '-92'], ['B2', '6', '-91'], ['B2', '7', '-77'], ['B2', '7', '-82'], ['B2', '8', '-88']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex - `<info> app: Bid=(\w+),Bts=(\d+),VAL=(-\d+)`

```
result = []
regex = r'<info> app: Bid=(\w+),Bts=(\d+),VAL=(-\d+)'

with open('list.txt', r) as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        result += re.findall(regex, line)
```